# How to restrict the max memory size of java HashMap?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a requirement where I read string from huge file and process it in HashMap. I want to throw exception when HashMap size is > 5GB. How do I set the max memory size of HashMap?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check the file size instead?

Comment: You subclass `HashMap` and override methods to keep track of what is allocated and freed, and throw the exception yourself.  Determining how much memory an object occupies is itself a significant task... how deep do you go if the object contains references to other objects?  This is a non-trivial specification problem.

Comment: Why do you need to throw an exception at 5GB? Can't you read and process the file in chunks? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You subclass `HashMap` and override methods to keep track of what is allocated and freed, and throw the exception yourself.

However, be aware that determining how much memory an object occupies is itself a significant task... how deep do you go if the object contains references to other objects?

This is a non-trivial problem of deciding what you mean and what you want to track.  There is no one-size-fits-all answer.

And, as suggested by @ModusTollens in a comment, this is likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).